# How can I cast json recursively using gson.fromjson

Tags: java, json, gson

Given I have the following json structure:

```
{
    "Role": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "bb1",
        "description": "desc1",
        "PermissionDeck": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "Permission": [
                    {
                        "id": "398"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "399"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "400"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "401"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "402"
                    }
                ],
                "Limit": [
                    {
                        "id": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I want to cast this into a `LinkedTreeMap result` so that its content could be a retrieved by:

`result.get("Role")` returns Map

and

```
result.get("Role").get("PermissionDeck").size() == 5
```

and

```
result.get("Role").get("PermissionDeck").get(0).get("id") == 398
```

basically makes gson.fromjson recursively go into the structure, and fold any nested structure into LinkedTreeMap until it gets to the most inner layer, which then gets into LinkedTreeMap

Is this possible without writing custom recursive methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The closest you'll get is with `JsonObject` and using the appropriate getter for each nested member. In other words, your code needs to be explicit about what it expects in the JSON.

For example

```
JsonObject result = new Gson().fromJson(theJson), JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(result.getAsJsonObject("Role").getAsJsonArray("PermissionDeck").size());
```

will print `1` since you only have one element in the JSON array named `PermissionDeck` in the JSON object named `Role` in the root JSON object.